# Find a command handler from a command type in modern C++

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I have a bunch of structs (commands) with a different names and data. And I have a bunch of command handlers. Client code sends a struct to the intermediator, and the intermediator should find a concrete command handler based on a command (struct) type. How can I do this without using a switch/if statements in modern C++?

```
#include <iostream>

struct Command {};

struct CommandA : Command
{
    int a = 32;
};

struct CommandB : Command
{
    double b = 56.43;
};

class ACommandHandler
{

public:
    void Process(CommandA command) { std::cout << command.a; }
};

class BCommandHandler
{

public:
    void Process(CommandB command) { std::cout << command.b; }
};

class Intermediator
{
public:
    void Delegate(Command command)
    {
    //How can I choose a concrete command handler here?
    }

private:
    ACommandHandler handlerA;
    BCommandHandler handlerB;
};

int main()
{
    Intermediator intermediator;
    CommandA a;
    intermediator.Delegate(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to pass a reference to `void Delegate(Command command)`? Unless you can make `Delegate` a template or change its parameter to something like `std::variant`, this is impossible.

Comment: Why do you need separate handler classes? Why not added `void Process()` to every command?

Comment: Because commands is meant to be send by user, and only server should know how to handle this commands.

Comment: Instead of a switch or if-else chain, you can make a lookup table.  The table can be static (easiest), or each command could register itself dynamically at program startup (trickier, but more flexible).

Comment: Please, can you make a simple code example? Something like <CommandType, CommandHandler>, and only one delegate function, which will assign any command to concrete handler using this table?

Comment: I gave an asnwer below, but made assumptions. If you give more detailed solutions on what you want to achieve, so what you want to do, then I can show you, how to do that and after that, I can write code for you. However, preconditions is that you explain in detail, what you want to do, so what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Hm. In my understanding your design or your approach to solve the problem is maybe wrong. Maybe, we are talking about a [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here.

It would be really interesting to understand what you really want to achieve.

Then, my next observation: I think you do not yet fully understand the meaning of **polymorphism** or how to use it correctly.

In your example code, there is nothing with **polymorphism** at all. There are no virtual functions and such.

And your `CommandHandler` are not derived from a common base class. At the first glance, it looks like there is a relation between the `CommandHandler` and the `Command`. But there is not. There is just an equal naming. For example  `BCommandHandler` could also have a `process` function that works on a Type  `CommandA`. This is somehow a strange concept. There should be a relation between the `Handler` and the `Command`.

Best would be to have the `process` function as part of the command class. That would be a more meaningful design and would eliminate nearly all problems. But as said: I do not know the reason, why you have chosen such a design.

Next, even if we would have a class hierarchy for the `CommandHandler` and try to invoke a virtual function through the base class pointer of a `CommandHandler`, we would still have, as parameter of the function, a base class pointer to the `Command`.

And this would require a so called **double dispatch** functionality. So, polymorphism on the called object and the given parameter. Unfortunately, the C++ language does not support **double dispatch** mechanisms. You can emulate it by employing the **Visitor** pattern from the GOF. But this pattern is notoriously difficult to understand and implement and creates problems with circular references. One very good solution can be found in **”Modern C++ Design: Generic Programming and Design Patterns Applied” by Andrei Alexandrescu**. There you can read about the Acyclic Visitor Pattern. A very good explanation.

Another solution would use templates for static/compile time polymorphism. But you said that you have many `command`s. And I fear you would get some substantial code bloating.

But since you have some fixed relation between a `handler` and a `command` you could maybe solve your problem using a `std::map` and some [RTTI](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) mechanisms. And with `dynamic_cast`

Not nice and probably expensive, but could be used in the below way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

struct Command { virtual void someDummyVirtualFunctionDoingNothing() {} };

struct CommandA : public Command { int i{ 42 }; };
struct CommandB : public Command { double d{ 43.2 }; };
struct CommandC : public Command { unsigned u = 44u; float f{ 45.6 }; };

struct CommandHandler {
    virtual void process(Command*) = 0;   // pure virtual function. Make Base class abstract
};
struct CommandHandlerA : public CommandHandler {
    void process(Command* com) {
        if (CommandA* ca = dynamic_cast<CommandA*>(com))
            std::cout << "Command Handler A:  " << ca->i << '\n';
    }
};
struct CommandHandlerB : public CommandHandler {
    void process(Command* com) {
        if (CommandB* cb = dynamic_cast<CommandB*>(com))
            std::cout << "Command Handler B:  " << cb->d << '\n';
    }
};
struct CommandHandlerC : public CommandHandler {
    void process(Command* com) {
        if (CommandC* cc = dynamic_cast<CommandC*>(com))
            std::cout << "Command Handler C:  " << cc->u << '\t' << cc->f << '\n';
    }
};
class Intermediator
{
public:
    void delegate(Command* command)
    {
        const std::string key{ typeid(*command).name() };
        if (dispatcher.find(key) != dispatcher.end()) {
            dispatcher[key]->process(command);
        }
    }
    // Commands are just dummies and used to get the type
    void addDelegate(CommandHandler* handler, Command* command) {
        const std::string key{ typeid(*command).name() };
        dispatcher[key] = handler;
    }
protected:
    std::map<std::string, CommandHandler*> dispatcher{};
};

int main() {
    // Define instances of command classes 
    Command* commandA = new CommandA();  // Dummy. Only needed for type deduction
    Command* commandB = new CommandB();  // Dummy. Only needed for type deduction
    Command* commandC = new CommandC();  // Dummy. Only needed for type deduction
    Command* commandAA = new CommandA();
    Command* commandBB = new CommandB();
    Command* commandCC = new CommandC();

    // Define Instances of command handler
    CommandHandler* commandHandlerA = new CommandHandlerA();
    CommandHandler* commandHandlerB = new CommandHandlerB();
    CommandHandler* commandHandlerC = new CommandHandlerC();

    // Add delegate function for types.
    // All pointers here are pointer to the base classes.
    // Here the commands are just dummies and only used to get the type.
    Intermediator im{ };
    im.addDelegate(commandHandlerA, commandA);
    im.addDelegate(commandHandlerB, commandB);
    im.addDelegate(commandHandlerC, commandC);

    // Call delegate. Please note. The commands are pointers to the abstract base Class 
    im.delegate(commandAA);
    im.delegate(commandBB);
    im.delegate(commandCC);

    return 0;
}
```

Please note: Raw pointer for owned memory should be replace by `std::unique_ptr` or other smart pointers.

And, as said above, I still think that this is the wrong design.

Maybe an **Abstract Factory** could help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct CommandA
{
    auto Do() const { return m_data; }
private:
    int m_data = 42;
};

struct CommandB
{
    auto Do() const { return m_data; }
private:
    float m_data = 3.1415f;
};

struct CommandC
{
    auto DoC() const
    {
        std::cout << "C" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Intermediator
{
public:
    template<typename command_t>
    auto Delegate(const command_t& command)
    {
            return command.Do();
    }

    // this will be the most specialized handler for CommandC
    auto Delegate(const CommandC& command)
    {
        return command.DoC();
    }
};

int main()
{
    CommandA a;
    CommandB b;
    CommandC c;

    Intermediator intermediator;
    
    auto value = intermediator.Delegate(a);
    std::cout << value << std::endl;

    auto pi = intermediator.Delegate(b);
    std::cout << pi << std::endl;

    intermediator.Delegate(c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's great, thanks. But how can I call a concrete command handler using this solution? And also, every struct should only contain some data.

Comment: Hey I updated the example to do just that. But not sure if this is what you really need in the end. .. looks like you need a dynamic_cast in your code since you pass a baseclass to the Intermediator.

Comment: I need a solution without using if and switch statements. My system handles more than a hundred commands, so it doesn't work for me, but thanks.

Comment: The "if constexpr" is evaluated at compile time! The runtime code will not have if/then/else :) Basically a specialized Delegate function will be generated for each command type and be called directly. I just realize that you could create a Delegate overload for each type and its behavior will be the same :)

Just have Delegate(const CommandA&) and a Delegate(const CommmandB&).
If all commands have the same method then a template is shorter to type (the if constexpr dissapears again)

Comment: I apologize for the confusion :) Updated the example again

Comment: Imagine a hundred of commands. In this case I’ll need a hundred of overloaded methods. This solution doesn’t work for me(.